# Can I trigger a S3 PUT event when moving an object from one S3 bucket to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to use AWS CLI or something else to trigger a S3 Bucket `PUT` event when I move an object from one S3 bucket to another? Or would I need to download the file and upload it again?

I believe using s3 api's `sync` or `mv` commands would only trigger a `COPY` event

Comment: What do you mean by "move"? There is no move command in Amazon S3. Are you referring to `CopyObject`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I was referring to this command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html Did I get some terminology mixed up?

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 mv` command makes things convenient for us humans. Behind the scenes it is actually using `CopyObject` and `DeleteObject`.

My testing shows that the `mv` command generates a `COPY` event in the destination bucket.